# Is it allowed for an app to ask for 5 stars with NO incentive?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-play-services

I am aware of Play Store policy against reviews with an incentive. But is it OK if an app just asks the user to leave  a 5 stars review if they're enjoying the app with no incentive whatsoever? Thanks!

Comment: It's not against [the policy](https://play.google.com/about/storelisting-promotional/ratings-reviews-installs/), so there is nothing wrong //what is your concern?

Comment: That's rather a question specific to Play Store and its policies, not to Android.But like @beeshyams I see nothing wrong with that, you also have it in other areas: "If you like this, spread the word!" As long as it's not bound to some condition ("you cannot continue using this app before…", or something alike).